# how to deploy maven progect in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I used to use myeclipse, now switch to eclipse, I do not know how to deploy maven project in eclipse, I also do not know how to use the eclipse maven plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two options

1. use [m2_eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin
2. go to project directory and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on commandline or terminal. and then import project in eclipse. also you need to add classpath variable M2_REPO (which is located at `<home_directory>/.m2/repository`) in eclipse. Detailed explanation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-configure-m2_repo-variable-in-eclipse-ide/)